# How do i calculate the force acting on a body when it hits the ground from free fall?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, free-fall

A body with mass $m$  is released from the height $h$ without initial velocity. Also i assume the impact is wholly plastic
upon impact with the ground ( at $ x=0 $ ) i want to calculate the forces acting on it.

I will first present my way :

1.Integrating acceleration
$a(t)=-g$
$v(t)=-g*t$
$x(t)=-\frac 12*g*t^2+h$

2.Get the velocity shortly/during before impact
$x=0$ ,so
$ t_{impact}= \sqrt{\frac{2*h}{g}}$ and $v_{impact}=-g*\sqrt{\frac{2*h}{g}}$

3.Now i use conservation of momentum. First because of my plasticity assumption, the velocity after the impact is 0.

$-m*v_{beforeImpact} = \int_{0}^{t_{impact}} F = \bar{F} $

i assume $v_{impact} = v_{beforeImpact} $ and get    $m*g*\sqrt{\frac{2*h}{g}} = \bar{F} $

========================================================================

Now my Questions :
1. First is this correct ?
2. How would i average $\bar{F} $ ? Deviding it by $t_{impact}$ ?But it would go to infinity if the $t_{impact}$ goes to zero.
3. How would i calculate the peak force ?

Comment: You can tell pretty easily that -m*v = ... = F isn't right. _kgm/s_ isn't the same unit as _kgm/s^2_.

Answer (score 1):

Your work is correct up until this line:
$$mv = \int_0^{t_\textrm{impact}}F\,\mathrm dt = \bar{F}$$
There are two mistakes here. First, the end result of the integral in terms of the average force is
$$\int_0^tF\,\mathrm dt = \bar{F}\Delta t$$
Second, the $t_\textrm{impact}$ in the integral limit is different from the $t_\textrm{impact}$ in your velocity equations. In the equation
$t_\textrm{impact} = \sqrt{\frac{2h}{g}}$, the time refers to how long the object falls before it hits the ground. The $t_\textrm{impact}$ in the integral is how long the collision with the ground lasts. These should be given different names to avoid confusion like $t_\textrm{fall}$ and $t_\textrm{collision}$.

As to how to calculate the force of impact, that depends on the specific object being dropped. You can imagine that a water balloon going splat against the ground would have a large $t_\textrm{collision}$ because it spends a lot of time deforming and flattening out on impact (see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90VyvOhPmA0)). This means that the force of impact is small. On the other hand, a baseball would have a very short $t_\textrm{collision}$ because it doesn't deform on impact and stops almost immediately, resulting in a large force.

Comment: The conclusion from this:  you can't calculate the force unless you know the duration of the collision.  You (the OP) don't have enough information.